# Out of Memory error on Nested loop C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, streamreader

I looked this up and I almost got it but i have this one remaining runtime error.
My code is the following:

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    while (reader.Peek() != '\r')
    {
        datalinestream.Add(GetWord(reader));
    }
    LuceneDB.AddUpdateLuceneIndex(new MATS_Doc( datalinestream));
    datalinestream.Clear();
}
```

The code is importing the data but the loop will not break and will crash out due to the following

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll"

What is the appropriate break conditions for the outer while loop to ensure I read the entire file and break at the end. I struggle with this since I need to advance to the next line and I need to skip the first row in the spreadsheet. Any help much appreciated.

****UPDATE****

I clear the list of strings since I am creating a doc for the lucene index and it only has about 14 fields in it and I do not want the list to get too large.

My code for getword

```
private string GetWord(TextReader inputdata)
        {
            String word = "";

            while (inputdata.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                word += (char)inputdata.Read();
                if ((word.Contains(";"))) break;
            }

        return word;
    }
```

Comment: What does `GetWord` do? How large is your file?

Comment: My file is quite small 15 kb. its only like 50 lines of semi colon delimited stuff. The code runs and it hangs like it stuck somehow.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing `GetWord` isn't advancing the reader - causing the `datalinestream` to get massive.

Or your file is really massive.

Out of interest - why are you throwing away `line`? - surely that contains all the text that you're trying to read on the inner loop?

**Update**

There must clearly be a logic hole somewhere in your code, and my guess is it's either adding `-1` or `0` chars to your list, or the inner string in `GetWord` (by the way, using `+=` on strings in this way is dreadful for performance and memory usage).  It could also be that your line terminators are not `\r` but just 'naked' `\n`.

That said, you could solve all your problems by doing it like this:

```
string line = reader.ReadLine();
string wordTemp;
while(line != null)
{
  string[] words = 
    line.Split(";".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
  foreach(var word in words)
  {
    wordTemp = word.Trim(); //get rid of any whitespace
    if(wordTemp.Length != 0)
      datalinestream.Add(wordTemp);
  }
  LuceneDB.AddUpdateLuceneIndex(new MATS_Doc( datalinestream));
  datalinestream.Clear();
  line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

As I say - don't throw away that line you just read - use it, exploiting the fact that it strips the newlines out too.  Then simply use `string.Split` to crack out each of the words, trimming them in the process to get rid of any trailing/leading whitespace they might have.

Comment: yeah - but if GetWord() doesn't advance it, then the `!='\r'` check will keep the code in the inner loop.

Comment: I see what you are getting at. Nothing stops the inner while condition from being true.

Comment: I think getword does work properly since I do actualy get the info into the program. The break just does not work. So I have to restart the program to pick up after the import.

Comment: Have updated my answer - I think you can achieve what you want a lot simpler (and more efficiently).

Comment: The code as posted has me stuck in an infiinte loop on the first row of data. Also the compiler is complaining about  word = word.Trim(); since it is the variable in a for each command.

Comment: Sorry - a couple of schoolboy errors - I forgot to put `line = reader.ReadLine();` at the end of the loop (otherwise it'll just keep looping as you've said).  And I've corrected the `word = word.Trim()` thing...

Answer (score 1):

this may cause the exception

```
     while (reader.Peek() != '\r')
      {
       datalinestream.Add(GetWord(reader));
      }
```

Comment: Code runs fine it just fails to exit the outer while loop. I am able to read all the data from the file. I need a way of breaking when the end of the file is reached and eventually shoots outs the run time error in like 45 sec of hanging.